# What is the name of this proof? And proof?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Firstly, what is the name of this kind of proof, title is free to edit and image to embed, I couldn't find it on the specification and didn't expect it to come up on the paper, I have no clue how to solve it, I'm used to numbers and all I get is letters :( I could've done more research had I have known the name of this kind of proof but, through many google's I couldn't get anything. Thanks if you can help :)

[image]

Comment: Is this supposed to be a two-column proof?  Where one column is for statements and the other is for reasons?

Comment: Two of the marks appear to need backing up with reasons.

Comment: @Skidushe, sorry, I don't understand at all what you mean by "Two of the marks appear to need backing up with reasons."

Comment: @tilper https://gyazo.com/c3c8e17fb6e085f01a593ef06bf87f86 I got a snipit, but I mean, I still really don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer is what you need:

Draw two lines perpendicular to $AB$ through both $X$ and $Y$ and call $C$ and $D$ their respective points of intersection with $AB$

If $Area(AXB)=Area(AYB)$ then $YD=XC$ because the base of both triangles is the same $=AB$

Now the triangles $XCM$ and $YDM$ are the same, only that $YDM$ is "upside down", so $XM=YM$ and thus $M$ is the midpoinf of $XY$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the given info, if $\;XK\;$ is the height of $\;AXB\;$ to $\;AB\;$ , and $\;YL\;$ is the height of $\;AYB\;$ to $\;AB\;$ , then

$$S_{AXB}=\frac{|AB|\cdot|XK|}2=\frac{|AB|\cdot|YL|}2=S_{AYB}\implies |XK|=|YL|$$

Now observe the quadrilateral $\;YLXB\;$ : we have both that $\;|YL|=|XK|\;,\;\;XK\parallel YL\;$, the last one following because both segments are perpendicular to the same line $\;AB\;$ . The above two properties *characterize* paralellograms, so $\;YLXB\;$ is a parallelogram, and thus $\;LK\;$ bisects $\;XY\;$ . Finish now the proof by showing that $\;XY\;$ also bisects AB.